# SharePoint Online - Changing Page Title to match view names

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, list-view, modern-experience

I have a SharePoint list "Todo". I have two views:

- All items
- Todo Summary

On my homepage, I am including a list in a web part. Rather than the Title of the list saying "Todo" I want it to say "Todo Summary".

This is the same name as the view I have selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of list web part will no change automatically when you change the list view from **Switch view options** dropdown.

---

If you are adding multiple web parts of list on same page, you can manually enter a name to list web part when you add it on modern page.

1. In Edit mode, after adding list web part, click on List name.

   [image]
2. Change the name as per your requirements like:

   [image]
3. Publish/Republish the page.

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use the List web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537)